# Good Introduction to chemistry textbook

Tags: reference-request

I want to learn basic chemistry, so which textbook do you think I should pick? It should be something both concise and clear. Thank you.

Comment: Hi user5204, welcome to Chemistry S.E. unfortunately this question is not appropriate for this site,( [see here for our guidelines](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) is too much subjective! Keep following us!

Comment: Anyway I got an answer that's it!

Comment: The problem is how can you say that is the right answer who can assure you that is a good introduction? I know that can be annoying but these are the rules of this site.

Comment: You're right, please can you give me your opinion?

Comment: I like [Kotz](http://www.amazon.com/Chemistry-Chemical-Reactivity-General-ChemistryNOW/dp/053499766X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1397652164&sr=8-3&keywords=Kotz+treichel+chemistry).

Comment: Okay thanks, I will buy it even if it's expensive.

Comment: I'd recommend "Why chemical reactions happen" by Peter Wothers and James Keeler (both lecturer-type people at Cambridge). I've read it, and it's been educational. On Amazon, it's £40, but I picked it up for £5 - probably one of the best books I've brought!!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ***Zumdahl*** **Chemistry**. It discusses most of the basic topics, and contains lot of exercises.

Comment: Zumdahl is great

Answer (score 1):

You need the knowledge and a working mastery of it.  Choosing a good book requires already knowing what is useful and not useful to you.  Prime the pump,

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/chemistry